# Github actions add enviroment files to run

Tags: linux, flutter, github-actions

I'm trying to create a google-service.json file which is needed for flutter to build when using firebase during a github actions run. I have the base64 encoded content in my secrets and i copy the decoded content to a new file in the android/app directory. However flutter does not seem to find the file even though when i cat i can see the content of the file. What could i be doing wrong

This is how i create the file in the first step
`

```
- name: Copy google servives
        run: echo "${{ secrets.GOOGLE_SERVICE }}" | base64 -d > android/app/google-services.json
```

`then when i run the flutter build command i get this error`

```
Run flutter build apk --release

 Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        
Note: /opt/hostedtoolcache/flutter/stable-3.3.0-x64/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-3.7.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/auth/FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  /home/runner/work/Rentals-Flutter/Rentals-Flutter/android/app/src/release/google-services.json
  /home/runner/work/Rentals-Flutter/Rentals-Flutter/android/app/src/google-services.json
  /home/runner/work/Rentals-Flutter/Rentals-Flutter/android/app/src/Release/google-services.json
  /home/runner/work/Rentals-Flutter/Rentals-Flutter/android/app/google-services.json


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 7s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          187.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

`

Comment: I figured it out you should be adding the the file in the same step you are executing the command that requires that file